# How do you find a channel using its name in Discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried using this to find a channel named "information" and to send a message in it:

```
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'information')
channel.send('test')
```

And using that code resulted in this error:

```
let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === 'information')
                                               ^

TypeError: message.guild.channels.cache.find is not a function
```

I tried `npm install discord.js` to update the package, but it still didn't work. I also tried `client.channels.cache.find`, But it ended up receiving the same error. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Is this code inside of a *message* event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs you're doing it right ...
but according to reddit, there is no need to call cache and you can just call :

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.find(
  channel => channel.name.toLowerCase() === "information"
)
```

this corresponds to what i am doing with my bot, and this worked a few months ago

```js
guild.channels.array().filter(c => c.name === 'General')
```

Seems like guild.channels is already a collection, don't know if it's a mistake in the Documentation or if it's a really recent version that changed that ...

### [edit] found the problem

in the documentation, there are two versions (up in the toolbar) **v12** (default) and **v11**

it seems like they added the `.cache` in the v12, but maybe this one is not on npm already.

they have an alert about breaking changes that links to this page
where they explain how to switch to v12 https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html

Comment: Correction: Discord JS v.12 is on npm and is installed by default.

Comment: I actually reinstalled discord.js and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this:

```
let channel = message.channel.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name.toLowerCase() === `information`
```

I think it didn't work because you need brackets around the variable channel.